# background image doesn't work on safari

Tags: css, safari

I am new to programming and i made my first website for a friend. www.goalstars.be but apparently the background image of the landingspage doesn't work tried the solutions posted here but nothing seems to fix it. i am runnning my head in the wall. I think i made a huge mistake somewhere.
hopefully someone can help me. thanks in advance

this is the css code i use for the header

```
header {

    background-image: url('img/landing.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #00AB1C;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: [iOS Safari doesn't support `background-attachment:fixed`.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment)

Comment: @Rob Them's fightin' words, pardner.

Comment: @Blazemonger HTML and CSS are document markup, not programming.

Comment: @Rob A distinction without a difference. It's on a computer, it uses code, it requires logic, it has bugs. To anyone who's not writing a dictionary, that's programming.

Comment: @Blazemonger It is not code. It doesn't use logic. It doesn't have bugs. You're wrong. I won't continue this discussion.

Comment: @Rob What's OP asking for help with, then, if it's not a bug in the logic his code? You're letting semantics get in the way of meaning.

Comment: @Blazemonger yup without the background-attatchement: fixed it works. thx for the answer but  now i dont have the desired effect :D is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: I would create a separate element or pseudo-element that can use `position:fixed`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Safari, so i **removed the negative z-index** and that worked for me

Comment: my original code was without the z-index then i searched stackoverflow and i saw that adding z-index will fixed it, too bad it didnt

Answer (score 0):

try below css code

```
<style type="text/css">
header {
    background:url("img/landing.jpg") no-repeat scroll right top #000000;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #00AB1C;
    z-index: -1;
}
</style>
```

Comment: didn't work :s visual studio also says not known css property. i alswo installed an auto prefixer and used it on the whole document. but thx for helping me